# Are grails domains inheritable?

Tags: database-design, grails, entity-relationship, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm trying to model a network of `Person`s. A `Person` can have many `Favorites`. These favorites are fixed and constantly expanding.

```
static hasMany = [favorites : Favorite];
```

Now I would like to have children of the `Favorite` domain class. In `Favorite` I have the `belongsTo` mapping:

```
static belongsTo = [person : Person];
```

Now in my child class:

```
class ColorFavorite extends Favorite
{
    String color;
}
```

Is this possible or am I thinking to far outside of GORM? What is the correct way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible, what you have proposed looks correct.
Take a look at the GORM documentation for more info:

- http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.2.3
- http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.2.3

cheers

Lee

Comment: I've been over the documentation and haven't seen anything specific to what I'm doing. I want to ensure (a) GORM won't run off creating an inefficient schema to fit in the `Favorite` parent object, and (b) this can't be implemented via an existing pattern. I guess I'll give it a shot and see.

Comment: As the documentation warns, you do need to be careful about the number of joins generated by the tablePerClass approach if you have a lot of subclasses. It's hard to say whether there is a better pattern to use without knowing more about the type and number of Favorites you need to have.

Comment: Currently two, but the possibility to have more. Probably not more then say 10 restrictions ever, however I want to avoid hard coding a bunch of `hasMany` definitions into my `Person` class.

Comment: Few minor changes and all my tests pass, I'm assuming I'm good to go. Thanks!